# AWK NR lookup with variable gives extra output

Tags: awk, records

I have two files.  One has a variable as field 1.  I am using this to look up a value in another file which has the variable as a record, followed by another record containing the information I want.  ie I am looking up 1 to find A or 3 to find C.

```
1
A
2
B
3
C
```

I should be able to get this easily with awk using the following line.

```
awk '{if ($1=="3") A=NR}{ if (NR==(A+1)) print $0}' FILEIN
```

output should be

```
C
```

instead I am getting an output with the first line, then the correct value.  ie

```
1
C
```

If I just put in the NR value rather than assigning a variable it gives me only the data I want.  If I put (A+2) it gives me line 2 and the line I want, so on and so on.   Any ideas as to why this is happening

Comment: don't forget that even at the beginning of your script `A=0`, so `NR==(A+1)` will still evaluate to `NR==1`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as shelter commented, at beginning the `A` wasn't assigned by a value, awk will take `0`, so `0+1, 0+2`... you see why you got the unexpected line.

you don't have to play with `NR` for your needs, if I understood your requirement right.

try this line:

```
awk '$1=="3"{getline;print;exit}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "1
A
2
B
3
C"|awk '$1=="3"{getline;print;exit}'
C
```

If you just want to fix the problem in your code, you add a `&&A`, like:

```
awk '{if ($1=="3") A=NR}{ if (NR==(A+1)&&A) print $0}'
```

and your line could be shorten as:

```
awk '$1=="3"{A=NR}NR==(A+1)&&A'
```

Comment: I don't quite get how the &&A works.  However, your first code is very nice since it finishes as soon as it find the line.  It runs much faster than the fixed version of my code.  Thank you!

Comment: @user2348290 it should be faster, because after it found the right row, it stopped further processing. However if you have many line with `3`, that line will only take the first case. don't know if this is ok for you. you didn't mention that in your question. ;)

Comment: Each line is unique, so you gave me the best possible answer without knowing it, saves awk looking through 40M lines.